# Using SLAM map in a custom node

Tags: navigation, rviz, turtlebot, asus-xtion-pro-live, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the SLAM Gmapping tutorial. I have used rviz to set the goal for the robot.

I want to write a program in which robot moves autonomously. Therefore, I want to ask how can I set the current pose and navigation goal in the code (cpp node) without using the rviz? And also how can I used the learned (and saved) map in my code (cpp node)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162506/using-slam-map-in-a-custom-node/) by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The goal can be set by using the `actionlib` server provided by the `move_base` node. There are tutorials on how to do  this.

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2